GO http POST request error - wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
I am currently receiving an error message while trying to make POST request with net/http package.
Error: request failed error: Post "https://some.url.gov.ss/tgd/STS/oauth2/token": read tcp 123.123.104.104:53387->123.123.153.251:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
I have read through most of the posts raised regarding this 'wsarecv' issue. However, I have not found any solution that would work for me. The weird thing is that I can make this POST request just fine with Python 'aiohttp' library, which is really annoying.
Also, it is this specif URL for token that fails, if I make request to other URLs using the same implementation it works fine.
main.go
type JSONcontent interface{}

var (
    transport = &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        },
    }
    client      = &http.Client{Transport: transport}
    vissPayload VISSPayload
    results     JSONcontent
)

func requestAccessToken(token string, vissPayload VISSPayload) error {
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
    data.Add("client_id", vissPayload.CERT_CLIENT_ID)
    data.Add("client_secret", vissPayload.CERT_CLIENT_SECRET)
    data.Add("client_assertion_type", vissPayload.CERT_CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE)
    data.Add("client_assertion", token)

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, vissPayload.CERT_TOKEN_URL, bytes.NewBufferString(data.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("request error: %v", err)
    }

    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    request.Header.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("request failed error: %v", err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed ot read body error: %v", err)
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &results); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal body error: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}


For the server I need to POST data form and receive an access token in response. However, I receive this TCP/TLS issue.
The API resource provider, provided example in PHP (which I do not really know and have not tested locally).
index.php
function getAccessTokenWithSertificate(){

    ... CERT stuff processing ...

    //Configuring URL & SSL
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, self::CERTIFICATE_TOKEN_URL);

    //Turn off all TLS security issues
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    //Return result in string
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Configuring headers
    $headers = array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "Accept: application/json"
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    //Configuring post request
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
        "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
        "client_assertion_type" => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
        "client_secret" => self::CERTIFICATE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "client_id" => self::CERTIFICATE_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_assertion" => $jwt,
        "scope" => self::CERTIFICATE_SCOPE
    ]);

    //Getting result
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $json["access_token"];
}

From PHP example I can tell that we disable SSL verify peer and host, and I tried to do the same with Go http.Client.Transporter, but it does not seem to be it.
And this is my Python 'aiohttp' example which works fine.
main.py
async def test_request_access_token(self) -> None:

    ... CERT stuff processing ...
    
    # Request access token
    request_headers = {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }

    # Set request payload
    request_payload = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
        "client_assertion": JWT,
    }

    # Execute async POST request
    # Trace request
    trace_config = aiohttp.TraceConfig()
    trace_config.on_request_start.append(on_request_start)
    trace_config.on_request_end.append(on_request_end)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trace_configs=[trace_config]) as session:
        async with session.post(
            certificate_token_url,
            data=request_payload,
            headers=request_headers,
        ) as response:
            payload: dict = await response.json()
            print("Request date: %s" % response.headers.get("Date"))

            if response.status != 200:
                print(f"Error: request returned: {response.status}")
                for key in payload.keys():
                    print(f"{key}: {payload[key]}")
            else:
                for key in payload.keys():
                    print(f"{key}: {payload[key]}")
                self.access_token = payload["access_token"]

I would appreciate any help on this, I have spent too much time on this.

It's possible that the server rudely closed the connection because the server didn't like something about the request. Try setting the User-Agent request header in the Go code to whatever default that the PHP or Python programs use.

@CeriseLimón, Thanks. But for some reason it started working. I am little bit lost why it was not working and now is. It seems now it works without Transporter and I do not need additional headers. The weird part, it started working when I changed the URL paramiter to older version of URL - made a request, switched back to the current version of URL and it worked. This seems like solution of turning TV on and off and issue is gone...

There might have been a failure on the server.  I suggested setting the User-Agent because the User-Agent is a difference between the the three programs.  Some services reject requests from some User-Agents.

@CeriseLimón But the user-agent is set by Go client (User-Agent: Go-http-client). Should it be updated to different value or I should set it myself? Now I cannot remember if the user-agent was sent to server when I had this issue. Also I just tested with removing the User-Agent header and it still processed the request normally.

Do nothing if your Go program is working as expected.  If the server continues to rudely close the connection on the Go program, then add request.Header.Add("User-Agent", <insert a known good value here>) to override the Go http client's default user agent.  The User-Agent value is a difference between the three programs and there are services in the wild that reject requests based on the user agent.

This might help others: I received the same error when testing Go code against an API where the port I was trying to hit was still closed.
